# iOS foreground launch image

Tags: ios, iphone, launch, foreground

iOS is taking a screenshot of my app and using that image when bringing the app into the foreground.  Is there a way to specify which image should be used while bringing the app into the foreground?  I'm wanting something other than the default ios screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

You could always try using the `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` methods to display the image and then remove it, respectively.